# SwiftUI does not show ProgressView until after task is complete

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a swift UI view that when tapped should show a progress view:

```
struct ProjectItem: View {
@EnvironmentObject var controller: ProjectController
@State var showLoadingIcon: Bool = false
let document: Document

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ZStack {
        Text(document.name).font(Interface.Text.PopoverDialogLabel)
        Text(document.editTime.toString(true)).font(.caption2).foregroundColor(.gray)
        if showLoadingIcon {
            ProgressView()

        }
    }
    .padding(Interface.Sizes.StandardPadding)
    .if(controller.editedDocumentID == nil) { $0.onTapGesture(count: 1, perform: {
                // Open Project
                showLoadingIcon = true //This occours after TransitionView
                controller.openDocument(document: document)
                TransitionView() //this happens before the progressView is shown
    })}
}
```

}

When tapped it can take a couple of seconds to open the document and we would like to show a progressView to the user to display something is happening. However the progressView will only show to the user after the document has loaded.
In the view controller the openDoucment simply calls part of an app:

```
    func openDocument(document: Document) {
    app.setProject(document.id) //this takes a few seconds 
}
```

`app.setProject(document.id)` is on the main thread and ideally, this will be moved to its own thread in the future but we cannot for now.
How can the progress view be displayed before the loadDocument call is made?

I have tried to wrap the  following into a Task{}

```
controller.openDocument(document: document)
                    TransitionView()
```

I have also made the openDocument call async and sync which did not fix the issue.
I have also disabled the transitionView call and can see from my breakpoints that `controller.openDocument` call occurs before the

```
if showLoadingIcon {
                ProgressView()

            }
```

switches to showLoadingicon is switched - meaning that showLoadingIcons is checked by the app after `controller.openDocument` is completed and is shown.

Comment: You are likely blocking the main thread with your methods. You should watch Meet async await

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are doing too much *controller stuff* in the view. Move the logic to control the view into the project controller.

---

In the controller – assuming it conforms to `ObservableObject` – add an enum and a `state` variable

```
enum ProjectState {
    case idle, loading, loaded
}

@Published var state : ProjectState = .idle
```

and you have to make `setProject` **really** asynchronous to indicate when loading the data has been finished

```
func openDocument(document: Document) {
    Task { @MainActor in
        state = .loading
        await app.setProject(document.id)
        state = .loaded
    }
}
```

Otherwise use a completion handler. As the code of `setDocument` is not part of the question you have to change it yourself.

---

In the view the conditional view modifier  `.if` is very bad practice because it's not needed at all. You can disable the tap gesture much simpler with `.allowsHitTesting`. To show the appropriate view switch on `controller.state`

```
struct ProjectItem: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var controller: ProjectController
    let document: Document
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                Text(document.name).font(Interface.Text.PopoverDialogLabel)
                Text(document.editTime.toString(true)).font(.caption2).foregroundColor(.gray)
                switch controller.state {
                    case .idle: EmptyView()
                    case .loading: ProgressView()
                    case .loaded: TransitionView()
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(Interface.Sizes.StandardPadding)
        .allowsHitTesting(controller.editedDocumentID == nil)
        .onTapGesture {
            controller.openDocument(document: document)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure thanks for this - however in the `openDocument` function I receive: the error
`Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.`

Comment: Please see the edit. You said that `setProject` runs on the main thread anyway.

Comment: Using your example, this does not display the progress view again until after the document has been load

Comment: As I said `setProject()` must be `async`.